# 2 modules share the same DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have 3 modules in my project: 1 for my smartphone, another for my smartwatch and the last one is the shared module.

On the shared module there is a DB that both the smartwatch and smartphone are using.

All the operations on this DB are being performed on the shared module so when I want to retrieve information for example I call a specific function on this module.

My problem: When I try to do some operation on the DB I see that it's like I'm having 2 different DBs, 1 for when the function is being called from the smartphone module and another for when the call is from the smartwatch module.

I guess that it's a problem with the context I supply when I create the DB. I tried already a variety of contexts (including application context) and also to configure the same shared user ID on each module but nothing worked.

The shared module is only for the DB so it doesn't have a UI, it also makes things a bit harder.

Comment: is your share module a singleton class ?

Comment: No, would it solve my problem?

Comment: If a shared module only contain implementation of one instance then it can be a singleton class. So that when any object uses the shared module they are editing the same object.